# Getting error while deserialize

Tags: webservices, json, httprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to deserialize a json request but getting error that

> Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [2,2]

please do help me out with this error. 
my code :

```
public class connectionStoS_ctrl {

String clientId = 'jhjhjkjkjh.kjkkjkjjujbhokkoio79088kjkjmm';
String clientSecret = '56657767';
String username= 'username@cloud.com';
String password= 'pasword';
String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;

public connectionStoS_ctrl(){
     requestToStoS();
}

public void requestToStoS(){

   //OAuth2 oA1 = new OAuth2 (12, 'test1');
   //OAuth2 oA2 = new OAuth2 (13, 'test2');

   List<OAuth2> oALst= new List<OAuth2>();
   //oALst.add(oA1);
   //oALst.add(oA2);

   Http h = new Http();
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.setBody(reqbody);
   req.setMethod('GET');
   req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com');//Note if my domain is set up use the proper domain name else use login.salesforce.com for prod or developer or test.salesforce.com for sandbox instance

   System.debug('Http Request body '+ reqbody);

   System.debug('Http Request  '+ req);


   HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

   System.debug('obj Authentication Http Response '+ res.getbody() );

   //string serialz = JSON.serialize(res.getbody());
   //serialz = '{' + serialz ;
   //System.debug('obj Authentication Http Response '+ res.getbody());


   OAuth2 objAuthenticationInfo = (OAuth2) JSON.deserialize(String.valueof(res.getbody()), OAuth2.class);
   System.debug('obj Authentication Info 1 '+ JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(), OAuth2.class));

   System.debug('obj Authentication Info 2 '+objAuthenticationInfo.oauth_token);

   //if(objAuthenticationInfo.access_token != null){

   //System.debug(' Inside oAuth ');


   Http h1 = new Http();
   HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
   //req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+objAuthenticationInfo);
   req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
   req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');

   System.debug('jsonstr_BODY '+req1);


   //req1.setBody(jsonstr);//Send JSON body
   //req1.setMethod('POST');
   //req1.setEndpoint(https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/callback+URL);//URL will be your Salesforce REST API end point where you will do POST,PUT,DELETE orGET
   //HttpResponse res1 = h1.send(req1);
   //system.debug('RESPONSE_BODY'+res1.getbody());

   //}
}




public class OAuth2{
     public String oauth_callback{get;set;}
     //public String issued_at{get;set;}
     //public String instance_url{get;set;}
     //public String signature{get;set;}
     public String oauth_token{get;set;}    
}
}
```

response body

```
<html>
<head></head><body onload="document.forms['workerForm'].submit()">
<form  action="https://ap1.salesforce.com/visualforce/session" id="workerForm" method="post" name="workerForm" >
    <input type="hidden" name="client_id" id="client_id" value="rCVPxkDShqbjaG_G1fAV" />
    <input type="hidden" name="client_secret" id="client_secret" value="hgj87687nb" />
    <input type="hidden" name="grant_type" id="grant_type" value="password" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" value="kjhd7824fdjds" />
    <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="https://streamingapi.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/streamingapi__ConnectionStoS_Received" />
    <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="username@cloud.com" />
</form>
```

Please guide me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common cause is that the server is responding with a HTML page that contains error information rather than the JSON. Typically the status code in the response `res.getStatusCode()` would also be some value other than the [2xx success codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

While you could figure this out using debug logging, its worth putting in code to handle problems in the future too such as:

```
    HTTPResponse res = new Http().send(req);
    if (res.getStatusCode() >= 200 && res.getStatusCode() < 300) {
        // Everthing fine
    } else {
        throw new MyCustomException('HTTP callout failed:'
                + '\nendPoint=' + req.getEndPoint()
                + '\nstatusCode=' + res.getStatusCode()
                + '\nstatus=' + res.getStatus()
                + '\nbody=' + res.getBody()
                );
    }
```

**PS**

From a quick review of [Digging Deeper into OAuth 2.0 on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) it looks like your request should be "POSTed to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token" but your are doing a "GET" of "https://login.salesforce.com".

Comment: yes @keith my status = OK and code is 200 every time but issue comes when I try to deserialize oAuth token from the response.

Comment: @Anu Can you add to your question the text that comes back in the body?

Comment: I have updated my question with response body please check.

Comment: @Anu See the PS.

Comment: Ho @Keith that was great. It is getting oAuth code now. Thanks can you please tell me after getting the oAuth we need to send the request again what need to be the setEndpoint for that.

Comment: @Anu I'm not familiar with the password flow but from the docs it looks like you don't need to make a further call. In other flows also you are sent a 302 response with a new location header to direct you to the correct Salesforce instance; again not familiar with the password flow.